# addClass based on variable value

Tags: jquery, html, input, filter

I'd like to add a class after someone types in an input form.  This works and highlights the word Advisory in my page:

```
var value = "Advisory"; 

$("a:contains("+ value +")").addClass("highlight");
```

This works and gives me an alert that displays what the user typed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$("#filterinput").change(function(){
var value = $(this).val();

alert(value);

});
});
```

But this does not work (I've tried all kinds of combinations of quotes, etc.):

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$("#filterinput").change(function(){
var value = $(this).val();


$("a:contains('"+ value +"')").addClass("highlight").load();


   });
});
```

Can someone please help?

Edited.  My code is really long, but here is a sample of the html I'd like to search.  The first example that is working highlights the whole text of "Advisory Council on Historic Preservation" because that is what is between the anchor tags.

```
<ul class="treebranch">
  <li class="govdocs"> <a href="http://www.archives.gov/federal-register/acfr/">Administrative Committee of the Federal Register</a></li>
  <li class="govdocs"> <a href="http://www.achp.gov/index.html">Advisory Council on Historic Preservation</a></li>
  <li class="govdocs"> <a href="http://www.abmc.gov/home.php">American Battle Monuments Commission</a></li>
  <li class="govdocs"> <a href="http://www.arc.gov/">Appalachian Regional Commission</a></li>
  <li class="govdocs"> <a href="http://www.access-board.gov/">Architectural and Transportation Barriers Compliance Board (Access Board)</a></li>
  <li class="govdocs"> <a href="http://www.arctic.gov/">Arctic Research Commission</a></li>
  <li class="govdocs"> <a href="http://www.afrh.gov/">Armed Forces Retirement     Home</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry- jquery, searching an html page.

Comment: notice the examples aren't consistent the first working one is using two " and the third (not working) is using once " and the other '.

Comment: `:contains` searches the text content of elements.  What is the content of your html a element you are wanting to find?  Can you post the html?

Comment: alonisser- thank you, I've tried it with all combinations of quotes like that, nothing worked.  Brandon, I added some of my html code.  Thank you everyone for looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `grep` for this instead of a complex CSS selector.

JsFiddle showing how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/GZHA4/1/

This will give you better control over how it matches. For example, if you want case insensitivity you can uppercase or lowercase both `value` and `$(element).text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `load()` after adding the class to the selected element? jQuery has two `load()` methods, one is an AJAX method to load data from the server and insert it into the selected element. The other is to add an event handler to an element to be executed once it has loaded in the DOM. Neither method seems appropriate here, what are you trying to do?

The last snippet you have posted [does actually work](http://jsbin.com/ecelik/1/edit), however, you need to blur the text input, by tabbing or clicking away from it) before the class name is applied to the targeted element. I removed the `a` selector from the `:contains` filter in the JSBin example and used a simple `<p>` instead.

You're better off using the keyup event on the input instead of the change event, then the class will be applied after a key is typed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  .highlight { color:red; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>woo</p>
  <input id="filterinput"/>

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {


          $("#filterinput").keyup(function () {
              var value = $(this).val(),
                  target = $(":contains('" + value + "')");

              if (!target.hasClass("highlight")) {
                target.addClass("highlight");
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had to add the selector because your code highlights everything (add some text around woo and it will all be red).  But I got it working, except that is it case sensitive, I think I can find instructions for that somewhere on this site.